# Automapper - Map a single object with array property to N number of Objects based on count of array

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an object that contains an array into a list of objects that don't have an array. For example:

Let's say I have this object:

```
public class SourceInformation {
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public Person[] People { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to map to this object:

```
public class Destination {
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But what I want is if I have N `Person` objects in my `People` property, I want N `Destination` objects in return when mapping `<SourceInformation, Destination>`

Each `Destination` object should have the relevant name information, but they will all have the same `Id` property.

How do I tell Automapper that 1 SourceInformation object maps to N Destination objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up creating a custom Converter and Profile.

Profile:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile {
    public MapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<SourceInformation, Destination>().ForMember(....);
        CreateMap<SourceInformation, IEnumerable<Destination>>().ConvertUsing<CustomConverter>();
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class CustomConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceInformation, IEnumerable<Destination>> {
    public IEnumerable<Destination> Convert(SourceInformation source, IEnumerable<Destination> destination, ResolutionContext context) {
        var destinations = new List<Destination>();
        foreach (var person in source.People) {
            var destination = context.Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
            destination.Name = NameUtilStatic.FormatName(person.Name);
            destinations.Add(destination);
        }
        return destinations;
    }
}
```

Then just calling the mapper (I use a DI injected mapper) so it was as easy as just saying `_mapper.Map<SourceInformation, IEnumerable<Destination>>(source);`

You'll have to load your profile first. Something like: `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<MapperProfile>(); });`

More examples can be found here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Comment: It's easier to just map source.People to destination and to [pass](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) source as parameter.